# Are term_taxonomy_id and term_id the same?

Tags: categories, wp-query, wpdb, join-tables

I have a custom query where I need a JOIN because I want to COUNT all the posts **of a specific category**.

So I checked the tables and I found out that table `wp_term_relationships` contains a reference to the `wp_term_taxonomy` table. The **`term_taxonomy_id`**.

However when I looked into the `wp_term_taxonomy` table again I found out that **`term_taxonomy_id`** and **`term_id`** are having the exact same values.

So are they always the same? Can I filter the results by category with only joining `wp_term_relationships` and using **`term_taxonomy_id`**?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same.

It is quite clear looking at the table names:

`term_id` is the ID of a single term, whatever taxonomy it belongs to. The other information in the table `term_taxonomy` is related to the term - the slug, the title etc.

`term_taxonomy_id` is the ID of the relationship between a single term and a taxonomy, and does not contain any other data.

Comment: So why are they having the same values? And can I rely on those for getting posts by category? (Then I would have no need of joining the category table)